# Your Device is not compatiple with this version

Tags: android

My Signed APK size is 61 mb I know that's why I am getting this error while trying to install app from play store but I don't know how reduce the size of this apk . I have removed unwanted code too from  code but still I am getting this size of APK.

This is manifest file code:

```
   <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="8" />

   <uses-feature
           android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"
           android:required="true" />
   <uses-feature
           android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />

   <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
            android:required="true" />
```

This is my gradle build:

```
         ext {
           minSdkVersion = 17
            targetSdkVersion = 28
            compileSdkVersion = 28
            buildToolsVersion = '28.0.0'

             releaseVersionCode = 1
             releaseVersionName = '1.0.3'
             androidBuildToolsVersion = '28.0.0'
             androidSupportSdkVersion = '28.0.0'

             supportLibraryVersion = '28.0.0'
             gsonVersion = '2.8.0'
             calligraphyVersion = '2.2.0'
             rx2AndroidNetworking = '0.0.1'
             retrofit = '2.1.0'
             picasso = '2.5.2'
             zxing = '3.2.1'
             circularimageview = '3.0.2'
             multidex='1.0.1'
             ormlite='5.0'
             okhttp='2.5.0'
             dagger2Version = '2.8'
             rxjava2Version = '2.0.5'
             rxandroidVersion = '2.0.1'
             butterKnifeVersion = '8.5.1'
             greenDaoVersion = '3.2.0'
             placeholderviewVersion = '0.6.1'
             debugDBVersion = '1.0.0'

             junitVersion = '4.12'
             espressoVersion = '2.2.2'
             mockitoVersion = '2.7.1'
             androidPlugin = 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' }
```

and this my gradle library:

```
       dependencies {
             compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
          androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
             core:2.2.2', {
           exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support- 
           annotations'
               })
             compile files('libs/ProwessSdkV2.4.6.jar')
             compile "com.android.support:appcompat- 
             v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
               compile "com.android.support:recyclerview- 
                  v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
               compile "com.android.support:cardview- 
                  v7:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
              compile 
          "com.android.support:design:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
           compile "com.android.support:support-vector- 
         drawable:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
         compile "com.android.support:support- 
           v4:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
            compile 
  "uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:$rootProject.calligraphyVersion"
        compile "com.amitshekhar.android:rx2-android- 
          networking:$rootProject.rx2AndroidNetworking"
        compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"
         compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
           annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger- 
         compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
          compile 
       "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:$rootProject.rxjava2Version"
        compile 
          "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxandroidVersion"

       testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
         androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
           exclude module: 'support-annotations'
                 }
          androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
              core:2.2.2') {
                 exclude module: 'support-annotations'
               }
               testCompile "org.mockito:mockito- 
          core:$rootProject.mockitoVersion"
          testAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger- 
                compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
             androidTestCompile 
             "com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
           intents:$rootProject.espressoVersion"
          androidTestCompile "org.mockito:mockito- 
              core:$rootProject.mockitoVersion"
            androidTestAnnotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger- 
        compiler:$rootProject.dagger2Version"
          compile project(':swipereveal')
           compile project(path: ':progressbar')
            compile project(':diagonalprofileview')
             compile project(':flotingspinner')
            compile project(':facerecoglibrary')
          compile project(':facerecognition')
          compile "com.google.code.gson:gson:$rootProject.gsonVersion"
      compile"com.mikhaellopez:circularimageview:
      $rootProject.circularimageview"
           compile "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:$rootProject.picasso"
                 compile "com.google.zxing:core:$rootProject.zxing"
          compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$rootProject.retrofit"
           compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter- 
        gson:$rootProject.retrofit"
             compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter- 
      jackson:$rootProject.retrofit"
             compile "com.android.support:multidex:$rootProject.multidex"
                compile "com.j256.ormlite:ormlite- 
        android:$rootProject.ormlite"
                   compile 
             "com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:$rootProject.okhttp"
                   compile project(path: ':floatingbtn')
                  compile project(path: ':navigation')
              compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.+'
             compile 'com.github.pwittchen:reactivenetwork:0.8.0'
          compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.8.5'
             compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson- 
          annotations:2.8.5'
          compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.8.5'
            compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
             compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.2.0'
             compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
             compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:2.0.2'
              compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
           compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.2.1'
          compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
          compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
          layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
           compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
              compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest- 
           template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
                 compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services- 
           auth:9.8.0'
          compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0'
             androidTestCompile "com.android.support:support- 
               annotations:$rootProject.supportLibraryVersion"
             provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
            compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.2'
                   compile 'com.github.esafirm.android-image- 
               picker:imagepicker:1.9.0'
}
```

Please let me know what can I do with this source code so that I can reduce the size of the apk.

Comment: "Your Device is not compatiple with this version" means the device OS level is not compatible with the specified on the gradle or the manifest

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce app size doing this(This are some common practices) :

- Remove unused resources.
- Minimize resource use from libraries.
- Support only specific densities.
- Use drawable objects.
- Reuse resources.
- Render from code.
- Crunch PNG files.
- Compress PNG and JPEG files for that use tinypng website to compress
  large file size.

**Out of above you may also try,**

- Libraries that you add to your code may include unused resources.
  Gradle can automatically remove resources on your behalf if you
  enable `shrinkResources` in your app's build.gradle file.

  `android {
     buildTypes {
          release {
              minifyEnabled true
              shrinkResources true
              proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
              'proguard-rules.pro'
          }
      }
  }`

**Final and best way that i would say to prefer is Android App Bundle :**

An Android App Bundle is a new upload format that includes all your app’s compiled code and resources, but defers APK generation and signing to Google Play.
check out about it in developer console and make changes for that this will definitely gonna help you.

Comment: There are two option while building apk , one is normal and second is build bundles , so second one I need to choose ?

Comment: Yes exactly, this will reduce a lot size of your app. For more info please check out this document:
https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle

Comment: but for publishing app I need to build signed apk not build bundles

Comment: I have reduced my app size from 60mb to 43 mb by removing unwanted code , but I want to reduce more

Comment: Now onwards google allow uploading app bundles, so you can upload it to play store.